# Replacing Scraped Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building that scrapes music tracks and some of the tracks names contain "FREE DOWNLOAD" or things of the like. I'm having difficulty actually removing this text from the track title and wondered if anyone can serve up a viable solution.

**Text/HTML Example**:

```
<h3> Egokind – The Rush (FREE&nbsp;DOWNLOAD) </h3>
```

I've tried an onLoad function that contains a jQuery replace function but nothing I try seems to be working. `($('h3').replace('FREE&nbsp;DOWNLOAD', ''))` (also tried 'html' as the selector.

All data displayed on the site is scraped via externally sources and displayed then displayed in my HTML using Handlebars.

**HTML Structure:**
*(each track is displayed as a `<li>...</li>` item*

```
ul > li > .track-meta > h3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try doing a regexp search/replace *before* rendering the data via handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var new_string = $('h3').text().replace('FREE&nbsp;DOWNLOAD', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("h3").text($("h3").text().replace(/FREE\sDOWNLOAD/g,""));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U6rHL/1/)